# Loading recurring CSV files into Azure db from On-premises

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

We are building a rapid application/quick-win solution which entails loading monthly CSV files from on-premise storage (i.e.) files into Azure blob/SQL tables. There are 4 files with each having 50000 rows and the month name is affixed in the file name.

What is the best known method of transferring these files into blob or storage while ensuring we somehow able to retrieve the month name from the file, old files on the on-premise folders are ignored and only new one's are loaded.

In the past, we could use SSIS to easily support this behavior but I am looking for cloud based solution such as Data Factory.

I have tried On-Premise to Azure Blob but i am not able to avoid old files to be transferred nor I can retrieve file name (though i can possibly use insert/modified date).

Any suggestions? Ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Data Factory is almost certainly the tool to do this.  It has date and time functions eg [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-functions-variables) to help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same needs couple of weeks ago and I decided to go for a solution that uses Azure Functions and the native Azure SQL BULK capabilities.

Azure function can be triggered as soon as a file is copied into a Blob Store (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob). You can have access to all file attributes and thus also filename.

The Azure Function will then just call a procedure in Azure SQL, passing the detected CSV file name so that it can be bulk imported into a table of your choice, along with all needed properties.

Full code sample and detailed instructions are available here:

https://github.com/yorek/AzureFunctionUploadToSQL

Answer (score 1):

You could use any upload to Storage Blobs or Azure Data Lake Store (potentially orchestrated with ADF) and preserve the file name structure.

Then you could use Azure Data Lake Analytics and U-SQL to cook the files into a CSV file using `EXTRACT` and `OUTPUT` statements where you use so called file set syntax to both pivot the file/folder names into the rowset and use a predicate to limit the range of files to be processed. That U-SQL job can again be orchestrated and parameterized via ADF. Then finally use ADF to move the resulting file to SQL Azure or if you use SQL DW, you can use Polybase on the resulting CSV.

Here is a simple example of a pseudo U-SQL script:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL @begin_date = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-01");
DECLARE EXTERNAL @end_date = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-08");

@data = EXTRACT col1 int, col2 string, date DateTime
        FROM "/path/file_{date:yyyy}_{date:MM}_{date:dd}.csv"
        USING Extractors.Csv();

@data = SELECT * FROM @data WHERE date BETWEEN @begin_date AND @end_date;

OUTPUT @data TO "/output/cookeddata.csv" USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Comment: Is there a step by step guide to achieving this?

Comment: The above is pretty much step by step outline :). You can find whitepapers and demos on the Azure Data Lake, ADF and SQL Datawarehouse documentation pages that can show you the individual steps I outline above. I will put an end-to-end experience description to my doc backlog.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand the solution in principal now and will probably work on this week. Though, i am still unclear on how U-SQL job can be orchestrated and parameterized via ADF? Where in ADF can i link up with USQL jobs?

Comment: Here is some documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-usql-activity